# Book request about elliptic curves, RSA and DSA

Tags: rsa, elliptic-curves, dsa, pgp, ssh

I understand that this question can be hardly downvoted, but so be it if someone gives me really useful references :)

I wanna learn difference (deeply) between RSA, DSA, and ECC, especially I am interested in ECC and its application in GPG and SSH protocols, I googled some MIT courses but they seem too brief for deep understanding, so, please advice :)

Aim: I wanna make some research on topics to become a skilled person in this area.

Comment: Welcome to SE-cryptography, please note that this site is not for such kind of questions. May be you should go to Quora to ask for book recommendations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an excellent resource that covers those topics: http://www.crypto-textbook.com/. And here's a [channel](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC1usFRN4LCMcfIV7UjHNuQg) that follows the book.